# Print all prime number lower than n in C++ ( file crash )

Tags: c++, crash, primes

I wrote a C++ program that prints all prime numbers lower than `n`, but the program keeps crashing while executing.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

bool premier(int x) {
    int i = 2;
    while (i < x) {
        if (x % i == 0)
            return false;
        i++;
    }
    return true;
}

int main() {
    int n;
    int i = 0;
    cout << "entrer un entier n : ";
    cin >> n;
    while (i < n) {
        if (n % i == 0 && premier(i))
            cout << i;
        i++;
    }
    ;
}
```

Comment: The right tool for investigating this is a debugger.

Comment: You execute `n % i` with `i == 0`

Comment: start at `i=1` instead

Comment: start with `n % i` with `i = 2`

Answer (score 1):

As [Igor](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1670129/igor-tandetnik) pointed out, `i` is zero the first time when `n%i` is done. Since you want only prime numbers and the smallest prime number is 2, I suggest you initialise `i` to `2` instead of `0`.

You want to print all prime numbers less than `n` and has a function to check primality already.

Just

```
while (i < n){
    if (  premier(i) == true ) 
        cout<<i;
    i++;
}
```

And while printing, add a some character to separate the numbers inorder to be able to distinguish them like

```
cout<<i<<endl;
```

P.S: I think you call this a C++ program. Not a script.

Edit: [This](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes) might interest you.